# Graph nomenclature

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

This concerns graphs that are sets of vertices and edges G={V,E}, not graphical depiction of functions.

Imagine a graph that is a 2D square mesh of vertices. Such a graph can be constructed, for example, by taking typical graph paper, mapping a vertex to each intersection of lines, and an edge to each line segment. The graph paper is thus a visual representation of an abstract graph G. While the visual artifact has spatial attributes (lengths of edges, angles between any three vertices, etc.), G has none of this, only the set of vertices and the set of edges.

Now in the absence of spatial reference, a graph thus derived will have some properties of interest. Most vertices will have 4 neighbors, in fact if V and E are allowed to be infinite, all will have 4 neighbors. And the graph will have planarity. I'm specifically interested in this kind of graph, I.e. ones that have the same properties one would get for those constructed by "copying a 2D mesh". (distinct from the family of graphs that are simply described by "each vertex has 4 neighbor", which could be non planar as the diamond lattice for example)

Is it correct to call the abstract graph G a "2d mesh", or is their a more appropriate name for this construct when explicit spatial attributes are excluded? Question generalizes for "2D triangular mesh", "2D hexagonal mesh".

Comment: Sorry this is a bit of a mess, trying to post from a smartphone. Trying to figure out, is there even a way to describe this kind of graph, without resorting to some visual recerence. May edit soon from a real device.

Comment: As for describing the graph without visual reference, you might say that $V = {\mathbb Z}\times{\mathbb Z}$ (Cartesian product of the integers by themselves) and $E$ consists of all pairs (of pairs) $((m, n), (p, q))$ such that either $m = p$ and $|n-q|=1$ or the other way around.

Comment: Check this out http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html

Comment: I think what you're looking for is this wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph . DaG is describing the unit-distance graph for $\mathbb{Z}^2$, but most everyone would understand what you meant if you said something like the "infinite grid graph".

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in the comments, the "graph paper" case (either finite or infinite) is a (square) grid/lattice/mesh graph. The generalization you mention at the end can be referred to with the same terminology: triangular/hexagonal grid/lattice/mesh graph. [Wolfram has chosen "grid graph" to mean "square grid graph"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html), but [wikipedia mentioned all three words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph).

Be careful, though. The phrase "lattice graph" [can also refer to a cartesian product of complete graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatticeGraph.html), which is not what you want. Also, The word "lattice" [can refer to a type of directed graph](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/09/18/lattices/) related to [lattice theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_theory) (part of order theory). There are also ["lattices" in group theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29) (better known as "lattice groups") which are related to what you're interested in, but aren't quite what you want.